# Adding Post data to XML String

Tags: php, xml, post

I collect data from a form like this :

```
$title = $_POST["title"];
$fname = $_POST["first_name"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
```

I want tot build an XML String and add the above post data. I have tryed the following and none of it works. It has to use "" double quotes !

```
$XPost = '
<MinPrice>$_POST["first_name"]</MinPrice>
';

$XPost = '
<MinPrice>"<![CDATA[$fname]]"></MinPrice>
';
```

Can anyone please assist. It has to use "" double quotes !

Full Example :

```
$strXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SubmitLead xmlns="https://test.com.co.uk/webservicerequest/">
<Address1>'.{$_POST['Address1']}.'</Address1>
';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add " around the value not single '.

```
$XPost = "<MinPrice>{$_POST['first_name']}</MinPrice>";
```

with dobule quote you can do this

```
$XPost = "<MinPrice>".$_POST["first_name"]."</MinPrice>";
```

Change your code like that.

```
$strXml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SubmitLead xmlns="https://test.com.co.uk/webservicerequest/">
<Address1>' . $_POST['Address1'] . '</Address1>
';
```

Comment: It has to use "" double quotes !

Comment: @TrevorPassell what you mean describe ?

Comment: @TrevorPassell i have updated the answer please check

Comment: I am sending it via Curl and so i collect the post data using double quotes $title = $_POST["title"] then i need to build a XML String using the Post Data. I have to use double quotes as the SOAP Header throws out an error if i do not use double quotes. Is there any other way to add the post data to the XML string, maybe using the variable name ?

Comment: @TrevorPassell yes check now

Comment: lol , i know that part . Sorry i dont think im being clear with my question. I need to get the post data into my XML String without using single quotes. I can use double quotes and anything else, just not single quotes. Thanks

Comment: @TrevorPassell sorry check now i have added the double quote only.

Comment: thank you but it is not working. I added a full example. The example starts with single quotes. It cannot have anymore from what i understand. The url's need to have double quotes.

Comment: @TrevorPassell what is output of that code and what is your desired output can you please post in question

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<?php
$simple = "<para><note>echo $_POST['first_name']</note></para>";
$p = xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($p, $simple, $vals, $index);
xml_parser_free($p);
echo "Index array\n";
print_r($index);
echo "\nVals array\n";
print_r($vals);
?>
```

Reference [xml parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse-into-struct.php)

Comment: It has to use "" double quotes !